# The blessing for not talking in shul

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, synagogue, speech-talking

I read in תוכחת חיים that , *"One who is careful not to speak in shul during davening will he blessed to see children, long life, great success, and will NOT suffer the pains of Gehinnom. He will never lack in his livelihood. After a long and successful life, his body will not decompose. Besides the aforementioned, there is a promise that Hashem will listen to all of his tefillos.”*

Does anyone know where in תוכחת חיים it says this?

Comment: Where did you read it? Do you not remember where you read it but you remember the exact wording??

Comment: Sounds like the Mishebeirach on those "please no talking in shul" cards.

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat similar to the famous Mi Sheberach for those who don't speak during prayers, compiled by the Tosafot YomTov after it was revealed to him in a dream that the ת"ח ות"ט crusader pogroms were a punishment for talking in shul.

It is meant to be said after the Torah reading on Shabbat.

It says:

> מי שברך אבותינו, אברהם יצחק ויעקב, משה ואהרן, דוד ושלמה, הוא יברך את כל מי ששומר פיו ולשונו
>   שלא לדבר בעת התפילה, הקב"ה ישמרהו מכל צרה וצוקה ומכל נגע ומחלה, ויחולו עליו כל הברכות הכתובות
>   בספר תורת משה רבינו ובכל ספרי הנביאים והכתובים, ויזכה לראות בנים חיים וקימים ויגדלם לתורה לחופה ולמעשים טובים, ויעבוד את ה' אלוהינו תמיד באמת ובתמים ונאמר אמן. ‏

He who blessed our forefather Avraham, Yitzchak and Yaakov, Moshe and Aaron, David and Shlomo, he will bless those who guard their mouth and tongue from speaking during prayers. the Holy One Blessed be He shall guard him from every trouble and distress and from every plague and illness, and he shall be subject to all the blessings written in the Torah of Moshe and all the Prophets and Scriptures, and he will merit live and healthy children whom he shall educated to nurture them to [become] Torah [scholars], marry them off and educate them to do good deeds, and he shall eternally serve Hashem truthfully. Amen. sincerely